# 3 sticky boxes in one box without the last floating out of the main box

Tags: css

I'm creating an application from scratch and i want 3 div boxes in a main container, the code is as follows

```css
body {
    background: black;
    margin:  0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}

.main-cont {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 6px;
}

.left {
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    position: sticky;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
}

.middle {
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    float: left;
    position: sticky;
    border-right: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
}

.right {
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    position: sticky;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-cont">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the last one is floating out, how can i help this?

Comment: can u plz send the html code?

Comment: Provide a proper [mre] of your issue, please.

Answer (score 2):

Your elements are 1px to wide to fit inside the element. (Because of the border)

Use `width: calc(100% / 3 - 1px);` or `box-sizing: border-box`

(The second one will put the border inside the element, instead of the outside)

Answer (score 1):

> its' break bcoz of the border so you need to add below CSS

```css
body {
    background: red;
    margin:  0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}

.main-cont {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 6px;
}


.bx-width {
 height: 100%;
 width: calc(100% / 3 - 1px);
 position: sticky;
 float: left;
 border-right: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.right{
 border:none;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="main-cont">
<div class="left bx-width">left box</div>
<div class="middle bx-width">middle box</div>
<div class="right bx-width">left box</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

border-left and right also included the width of the three `div` so it's floating out,

add `*{ box-sizing: border-box;}` it will apply the box-sizing to all the elements.

```css
body {
    background: black;
    margin:  0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  
}
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-cont {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 6px;    
}

.left {
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    position: sticky;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    
}

.middle {
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    float: left;
    position: sticky;
    border-right: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
 
}

.right {
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    position: sticky;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-cont">
        <div class="left">

        </div>
        <div class="middle">

        </div>
        <div class="right">

        </div>       
   </div>
```